# Filtering both parent and child arrays of objects by child object's property

Tags: javascript

```
const Person = [
    {
        firstname: "john",
        lastname: "doe",
        items: [
            {
                visible: true,
                foo: "bar"
            },
            {
                visible: false,
                foo: "bar"
            },
            {
                visible: true,
                foo: "bar"
            },
        ]
    },
        {
        firstname: "jane",
        lastname: "doe",
        items: [
            {
                visible: false,
                foo: "bar"
            },
            {
                visible: true,
                foo: "bar"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        firstname: "john",
        lastname: "adam",
        items: [
            {
                visible: true,
                foo: "bar"
            },
            {
                visible: false,
                foo: "bar"
            },
            {
                visible: false,
                foo: "bar"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

In the above scenario, how can I filter `Person` array of oject by either ONLY the `visible: true` or `false` `items` array of objects?

So once filtering is done, `Persons` array will only have Person objects, for which, each `item` object will only have `true` OR `false` objects.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using `Array.reduce` and `Array.filter`:

```js
const data = [{ firstname: "john", lastname: "doe", items: [{ visible: true, foo: "bar" }, { visible: false, foo: "bar" }, { visible: true, foo: "bar" }, ] }, { firstname: "jane", lastname: "doe", items: [{ visible: false, foo: "bar" }, { visible: true, foo: "bar" } ] }, { firstname: "john", lastname: "adam", items: [{ visible: true, foo: "bar" }, { visible: false, foo: "bar" }, { visible: false, foo: "bar" } ] }, ]

const filter = (arr, v) => arr.reduce((r,{firstname, lastname, items}) =>
  [...r , {firstname, lastname, items: items.filter(x => x.visible == v)}], [])

console.log('visible:', filter(data, true))
console.log('not visible:', filter(data, false))
```